# Corrupt iTunes Match files

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes-match

I have an iPhone 4S (v5.1.1, jailbroken with Absinthe). I have been having lots of trouble with iTunes Match lately. Sometimes when I download a song, it will not play in the iPod player. I tap a song, and it plays the next file instead of the one I selected.

Using iFile, I verified that the file has actually downloaded to the filesystem (/var/mobile/Media/Purchases), and opened it from there using iFile's built-in audio player. It plays here, but there are gaps in the music (i.e. the first 2 seconds play, 30 seconds of silence, song resumes, 2 seconds of silence, resume, etc).

Has anyone else seen behavior like this? What could possibly be causing this? It happened on a fresh install of 5.1.1, before I jailbroke my phone, and has continued.

Comment: What happens if you redownload the file on the iPhone? Or on your computer?

Comment: If I delete the file and redownload, it usually works. It happens with matched songs, not just uploaded ones.

Comment: The gaps mean that the file has not downloaded properly. Delete it and download it again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Randolph. I realize that the file didn't download properly. Just wondering why that is happening so often for me.